# sending/receiving Attachments in WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, service, attachment

In my RESTful WCF project I need to receive an image attachment.
I dont know how to send /receive attachments in WCF REst Service.
In my WCF Service I will receive an image attachment from a mobile App.
I dont know how to write the code.
I appreciate if you can forward some examples and code.
I am new to WCF.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am surprised, I didn't get a single reply..Any help please

Comment: REST is about resources, not "attachments". Think of it that way.

Comment: You mean we cannot attach an image using REST WCF Service?

Comment: I mean you're thinking about it the wrong way. Assume that you're trying to attach the image to a "Contact" object. Then you might "attach" the image by doing a POST to /Contacts/1234/Images.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach images to a REST WCF Service. Implement PUT or POST and submit.

```
[WebInvoke(Method="PUT", UriTemplate =...
```

Here is a discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/6da8261d-152c-4053-9254-84cf6e7e1573/

Comment: Hi Thanks for the link. But it shows only reading the image. It doesn't show how to save the file and where to save the file.I need to save the received file to database/folder. I apprecaite if you could provide some code .